# Applying Cauchy's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

[image]

Why is the part highlighted in green equal to zero?

Comment: Where do get the impression that it is? They don't make it disappear; they wrap it into the first integral.

Answer (score 1):

Since $z_0$ is inside the unit disc, $\bar{z}_0^{-1}$ is outside the disc, and in particular not inside the contour of integration. Hence, by Cauchy's Theorem, the underlined integral is zero.